# How to verify CVE-2022-22965

Tags: cve-2022-22965, spring4shell

Suppose I have a website hosted at http://localhost:8000/helloworld/greeting. If I want to run the Python file (https://github.com/fullhunt/spring4shell-scan), do I need to run it on every endpoint, such as /home, /dashboard, or is it enough to check if only the index page is vulnerable or not? Ultimately, if the index page is vulnerable or not vulnerable, can we infer the same for the entire website?

I have tried only on index page and it shows it is vulnerable.